# Creating objects on the stack

Tags: c++

I have a class which contains a large vector

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int size)
private:
    vector<int> myVector;
}

myClass::myClass(int size)
{
    myvector = vector<int>(size);
}
```

If I call `myClass o(100000)` the object is created on the stack. However, what is exactly on the stack ? How much memory do I allocate from the stack ? The contents of the vector should be allocated on the heap, right ?

Can someone explain to me what exactly is on the stack and what is on the heap ?

Comment: You can use `sizeof(o)` to find out.

Comment: Or just look at your implementation of vector<>. Each piece of data on the stack has a fixed size, so you can put new items on top of it. If the content of the vector was on the stack, there would be a limited number of items that you can insert into it.

Comment: Yoy may just check what amount of data is on the stack with `sizeof(myClass)`. Size of stack memory will be constant whatever size your vector have.

Comment: @5gon12eder thank you

Answer (score 6):

Essentially you can generalize `std::vector` as

```
template<typename T>
struct vector {
    T* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};
```

Individual implementations may vary but they'll usually look something like the above.

So it's just this vector-container that is created on the stack, the array in which the data will be held is drawn from the heap.

--- Edit ---

For a given stack variable, you can tell how much stack space it requires with the `sizeof` operator, e.g.

```
myClass o(100000);
std::cout << "o's size is " << sizeof(o) << "\n";
```

Comment: Can you tell me how many bytes of memory I allocate on the stack with the line `myClass o(100000);` ?

Comment: No, but you can, with `sizeof`. e.g. `std::vector<int> v; std::cout << sizeof(v) << "\n";`

Comment: Or `sizeof(o)` given your `myClass o` example.

Comment: So, my understanding is that in order to actually have a stackoverflow, you really have to create a bazillion of objects on the stack with many variables in them. Otherwise the numbers just don't add up to produce a stackoverflow.

Comment: Depending on your stack size; under Windows the default stack size is 1Mb so you would need `2^20 / sizeof(thing)` things to overflow the stack :)

Comment: In a good environment, stack size should not be limited, i.e. it should be  limited only by the amount of memory in your device. If you are sure that you are not making a memory-critical program, stack overflow usually means some error in the code.

Comment: @IvanKuckir how would you set up the stacks for a program with 50 threads?  (each thread should have its own stack, of course)